# AvFoundation's AvPlayerItem timebase notifications fire 4 to 8 times per second

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avplayeritem

I'm trying to monitor the playback rate of an AvPlayerItem. According to the timebase docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1387605-timebase), the best way to do this is by subscribing to the kCMTimebaseNotification_EffectiveRateChanged notification.

So I set up the observer this way:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeBaseEffectiveRateChanged:) name:(__bridge NSString *)kCMTimebaseNotification_EffectiveRateChanged object:(__bridge id)(self.currentPlayer.currentItem.timebase)];
```

The selector is implemented to simply log the rate of that playerItem:

```
- (void) timeBaseEffectiveRateChanged: (NSNotification *) pNotification{  
    if (self.currentPlayer && self.currentPlayer.currentItem && self.currentPlayer.currentItem.timebase) {  
      ASMELogDebug(@"into timeBaseEffectiveRateChanged to %f", CMTimebaseGetRate(self.currentPlayer.currentItem.timebase));  
    }else {  
      ASMELogDebug(@"into timeBaseEffectiveRateChanged. Something is not set");  
    }  
}
```

I noticed in my logging that the timeBaseEffectiveRateChanged handler is called multiple times each second, and that the rate of the timebase is not changed (it's always 1.0000).

How should this notification be used properly so that it is only called when the rate of the playerItem actually changes?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @hybridcattt I'm now using a key-value observer on the rate property

Answer (score 1):

The event you've subscribed to is fired when the "effective rate" of the timebase has changed, but this does not mean that the "rate" has changed, as the rate is defined relative to its own host timebase. The documentation page for [CMTimeBase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmtimebase) has a section on this:

> If a timebase has a host timebase, the host timebase's rate is a factor in determining the timebase's effective rate. In fact, a timebase's effective rate is defined as the product of its rate, its host timebase's rate, its host timebase's host timebase's rate, and so on up to the ultimate host clock. This is the rate at which the timebase's time changes relative to the ultimate host clock.

What you're looking for is [CMTimebaseGetEffectiveRate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489313-cmtimebasegeteffectiverate):

> **CMTimebaseGetEffectiveRate**
>
> Gets the effective rate of a timebase (which combines its rate with the rates of all its host timebases).